# Why am I not getting the right output?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, inversion

I'm trying to count the number of inversions in an array. I'm getting the result of 3 when it should be 4. Here's my code.

```
 int[] array1 = new int[5];
 array1[0] = 3;
 array1[1] = 7;
 array1[2] = 10;
 array1[3] = 6;
 array1[4] = 4;

 int count = 0;
for(int i =0;i<array1.length;i++){

    for(int j =i+1;j<array1.length;j++){

        if(array1[i]> array1[j] ){

        count++;
    }
}
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Anyone know why its doing this? thanks

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException here. You are incrementing 'i' up to array1.length. It should be '<' not '<='

Comment: why i++ j++ inside for loop. please check for loop increment logic.

Comment: thanks for the tip, i changed it however im still getting 3

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comments, you need to remove those variable increments at the end of each for loop, and change the "<=" symbols to "<".

Comment: why should this be 4? what is an inversion in this case?

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to accomplish with the loops?

Comment: sorry its actually 5 i'm after, 7>6, 7>4, 10>6, 10>4 and 6>4

Comment: i've made some changes, now i'm getting 6

Comment: that makes no sense. where is the value of array1[0] being compared?

Comment: in the if statement when i is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove j++ and i++. Also change the initial position of j to i+1, instead of 0.

```
int[] array1 = new int[5];
array1[0] = 3;
array1[1] = 7;
array1[2] = 10;
array1[3] = 6;
array1[4] = 4;

int count = 0;
for(int i =0;i<array1.length;i++){

    for(int j=i+1;j<array1.length;j++){

       if(array1[i]> array1[j] ){
          count++;
       }

    }
 }
 System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: I had done what you suggested before hand and I was getting 6, but from changing j from 1 to i + 1 it worked :d thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `i++` and `j++` index incrementation should not be repeated in the body of your `for` loops as they already exist in the same line of the `for` loop conditions.